# PostgreSQL show latest date and one value of a column from many

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a problem with a query, that i can't figure out. Have tried for some time, but I just can't figure it out. Would be a great deal of help if you could help me. So... I have 4 tables:

```
cars - ID, make, model, plate_number, price, type, year, owner_ID
persons - ID, name, surname, pers_code
insurance_data - company_ID, car_ID, first_date, last_date
companies - ID, title
```

My query so far is..

```
SELECT cars.plate_number, persons.name, persons.surname, insurance_data.last_date
FROM cars,persons,insurance_data
WHERE cars.owner_ID = persons.ID AND cars.ID = insurance_data.car_ID
```

This outputs cars plate number, owner of the car, and the last date of the car's insurance. But the problem is that there's two cars that have two end dates of insurance, so in the output there's two entries for same car and with both insurance end dates. What i need is that there would be only one entry for each car and corresponding insurance end date should be the latest.

I know this is pretty basic, but i'm a first year student of databases, and this is one of my first assignments. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

(2) Use table aliases!

The answer to your question is `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.plate_number) c.plate_number, p.name, p.surname, id.last_date
FROM cars c JOIN
     persons p
     ON c.owner_ID = p.ID JOIN
     insurance_data id
     ON c.ID = id.car_ID
ORDER BY c.plate_number, id.last_date DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I'll keep in mind your suggestions.